# How to use prisma with the use-client declaration?

Tags: asynchronous, next.js, async-await, prisma

So I am trying to fetch data from the database. But as it's impossible to use Prisma and client-rendering in one file, I have one file in which I use Prisma to fetch data and second file to use those async functions wtih useState and useEffect:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function main() {
  const data = await prisma.book.findFirst({
    where:{
      title:"TheLeanStartup"
    },
    select:{
      id:false,
      author:false,
      title:true,
      rating:false,
      image:false,
      tags:false
    }
  });
  return data;
}

export async function fetchBook(request) {
    try {
      return await request();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  }
```

In the second file, I am trying do render these data using state and effect:

```
'use client'
import {fetchBook, main} from '@components/Book-Subside/afuncs';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Review() {
  const [book, setBook] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let result = fetchBook(main);
    setBook(result);
  }, []);

  if (!book) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <h1>{book.title}</h1>
  );
}
```

Can somebody explain how to make this code to work, because all I get is bunch of errors.